# How to trigger JavaScript Function when 10 seconds of youtube video has been played

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I want to know how to trigger JavaScript function when user has watched 10 seconds of video on youtube embed on my blog.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Where are you encountering the error? SO is for *specific* coding difficulties.

Comment: I am beginner at this level i dont know how to use youtube apis

Answer (score 0):

You can tell what time the player's at using the [getCurrentTime](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#getCurrentTime) method, which you'd call in a function passed to setInterval.  You can start and stop the timer on play and pause events sent to the [onStateChange](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onStateChange) handler.

If you'd rather account for ten seconds of playback, rather than being past the ten second mark in the video, then starting a countdown timer to call your function on the start event and stopping it on the buffering and paused events would be your best option.